# How to CURL a twitter page

Tags: curl, twitter, command-line, terminal

I am using a CURL request to try to get the HTML of individual twitter pages. CURL functions correctly for most sites I request, but when I try any twitter web addresses, I come up with nothing. I do not get an error message, just nothing.

What I have tried requesting so far are the following:

```
$> curl twitter.com/username

$> curl www.twitter.com/username

$> curl http://www.twitter.com/username
```

and each one does not produce any output.

Any tips/advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: use the `-v` option and it will tell you why.

Comment: I used the -v option but I still don't know why its not working. :(

Comment: update your question with the output then...

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's first response to all those URLs is a redirect, use the `-L` switch to follow them. For Example:

```
curl -L twitter.com/pii_ke
```